# Critical section in a "threading" class

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a class which inherits from threading.Thread. The run() method in this class updates a field. If I want to access this field (read only) with a getter method, do I have to use a lock? The run() method is the only one which writes the field.

Edit:

It's really a simple class, something like this:

```
class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._field = None
    def run(self):
        # connects to a REST API and updates self._field
    def get_field():
        # do I need to put a lock here
        return self._field
```

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's check it using dis!

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Client.get_field)
 11           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_field)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Theoretically, loading the attribute is done in a single instruction, but returning the value is not. Between loading the attribute and returning the value, it could already have been changed by a thread. So the takeaway is to use a lock. Even if the whole operation was atomic (accessing directly client._field), not using a lock is discouraged. [Google style guide states that:](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#218-threading)

> Do not rely on the atomicity of built-in types.